# reemplazar rs.fields(i) por variable

Tags: sql-server, asp

estoy realizando una consulta a traves de sqlserver, pero quiero saber como puedo reemplazar rs.fields(i) por una variable, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente query

```
sSQL="SELECT ID, NOMBRE, FECHA, DETALLE FROM PERSONAL WHERE ID=63254"
Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL) 
while not rs.EOF
  for i = 0 to rs.fields.Count - 1
     response.write(rs.fields(i))
  next
  rs.movenext
wend
```

Y el resultado de ese query me entrega los siguientes datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si imprimo rs.fields(i), me arroja el siguiente resultado

1000
PEDRO
16-09-2019
1 PEDIDO

1001
JUAN
15-09-2019
5 PEDIDOS

1002
ANDRES
13-09-2019
3 DESPACHOS

1003
LUIS
14-09-2019
4 ENTREGAS

1004
MARCELO
02-09-2019
NO VINO

Lo que me gustaria saber es como asignarle una variable a la posicion, es decir `ID1 = rs.fields("ID")` em entregue como resultado 1000 `ID2=rs.fields("ID")` me entregue 1001, etc

Comment: Hasta dónde recuerdo, puedes hacer `rs.fields("ID")` y obtener el valor de la columna `ID` del registro actual. ¿Lo que buscas es inicializar tantas variables `IDn` por cada valor de la columna para cada fila? ¿es eso realmente? ¿que ocurre si tienes un recordset con un millón de filas?

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, pero lo que si se es que no tengo más de 10 filas en el registro que consulto, y siempre será asi, ya que yo genero una tabla con js en asp de manera automatica, donde el parametro máximo es de 10 filas, entonces si el dato ya lo tengo registrado me deberia mostrar dicha información (no se si me explico)